# Find out if inside a model callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Sometime I want a method which can be used standalone and within Rails callback to behave a little differently. I want `save()` call inside my method to be ignored if it is within callback.

So is there a method in Rails to say if I am currently in the context of ActiveModel callback. The last resort would be using backtrace, but I hope there is a nicer solution.

### update

My model has some kind of state machine. One event transition is `make_bid`. During the `before_create`, I want to call that and create a Bid. If creation succeeds, `make_bid` then sets the state to be `bidded`.

Now, it makes sense to `save` in this method, since it is a event transition method. However if `save` is called, since it is in a `before_create`, stackoverflow would occur.

This `make_bid` method is also being called from other contexts which are not model callbacks, which we do want `save`.

So the only way is to find out whether we are within a callback, if it is, then don't save, otherwise, save.

Comment: Can you explain further what you are hoping to do?

Comment: I want to know a way to determine if currently I am within a callback, e.g. `save if !in_callback?`

Comment: You can use something like `Model._save_callbacks` to get the list of callbacks. See the 'Debugging callbacks' section of the docs for more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: I'm almost certain that this smells like bad design. If you can explain the overall intent of your code we can help you find a better way to achieve what you want. Even if there were a way, it sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @Mohamad I have added my design. not sure if this makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Why not refactor your 'make_bid' method to separate the state machine interaction logic from the persistence logic and then create dedicated methods for each transition that leverage the common code but do things differently where they need to ( call 'save' in one case and not the other)

Comment: How about just set bidded on the model after the first child bid is created?

Comment: @YevgeniyGoyfman just it is common for state machine related gems to have event method like `make_bid` which actually saves data. I try to follow that convention. But I guess you are right that splitting it would avoid this problem all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag to avoid infinite recursion:

```
def make_bid
  return if @making_bid
  @making_bid = true
  ...
  save
  @making_bid = false
end
```